# Epson_XP_7100 No scanner access

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, scanner, epson

I can access almost all my printer options, but I have no access to the scanner. I have tried with Image Scan v3 and Simple Scan, but neither of them worked.

My settings on Kubuntu 18.04:

[image]

Comment: 1. Kubuntu 18.04 as well as all the Ubuntu flavors of the same vintage are already out of support therefore off-topic here. Please upgrade to a supported release. 2. Epson MFPs often need proprietary drivers, at least for the scanner part.

Answer (score 0):

Install a scanner driver from [HERE](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Download the tar.gz, extract it and run

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

from there.

Comment: looks like it got stuck on " triggers" ..

Comment: Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ..
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...